# Merge two Worksheet_Change events in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble merging two events into one.

The first code changes all cells containing **"Black"** and **"White"** to **"Grey"** whenever **"A"** on same row changes value.

**Code 1:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
Dim oRng As Range
Dim oCell As Range

If Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Set oRng = Target.Parent.Range("B" & Target.Row & ":" & Target.Parent.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Parent.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Address)

        For Each oCell In oRng
            If oCell.Value = "Black" Then
            oCell.Value = "Grey"
        End If
    Next

       For Each oCell In oRng
            If oCell.Value = "White" Then
            oCell.Value = "Grey"
        End If
    Next

        
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    

End Sub
```

The second code calls a certain mailmacro whenever **"Black/WHite"** changes to **"Grey"** on that column.

Code 2:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
        If Intersect(Range("B:B"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    
             If Target.Value = "Grey" Then
        
                Call Mail1
            
            End If
            
    ElseIf Intersect(Range("C:C"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    
             If Target.Value = "Grey" Then
        
                Call Mail2
             
            End If
            
        End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Both codes works on their own, but I cant get the macro-calls to work when trying to merge them, but I also don't get some sort of error message. It just does not Call the macros.

Example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
Dim oRng As Range
Dim oCell As Range

If Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Set oRng = Target.Parent.Range("B" & Target.Row & ":" & Target.Parent.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Parent.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Address)

        For Each oCell In oRng
            If oCell.Value = "White" Then
            oCell.Value = "Grey"
        End If
    Next

        For Each oCell In oRng
            If oCell.Value = "Black" Then
            oCell.Value = "Grey"
        End If
    Next


If Intersect(Range("B:B"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    
    If Target.Value = "Grey" Then
        
        Call Mail1
            
    End If
            
ElseIf Intersect(Range("C:C"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    
    If Target.Value = "Grey" Then
        
        Call Mail2
             
    End If
        
End If
        
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Any suggestions? Thank you all

Comment: `If Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub` - you exit if the first condition isn't met... which prevents you from getting to the next condition (column B) most likely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I refactored the code below. This should work. BigBen is correct in his comment.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
Dim oRng As Range
Dim oCell As Range

If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Range("A:A")) Is Nothing 

    Set oRng = Target.Parent.Range("B" & Target.Row & ":" & Target.Parent.Cells(Target.Row, Target.Parent.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Address)

        For Each oCell In oRng
            If oCell.Value = "White" or oCell.Value = "Black" Then
                oCell.Value = "Grey"
            End If
        End If
    Next

End If

If Not Intersect(Range("B:B"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    
    If Target.Value = "Grey" Then
        
        Call Mail1
            
    End If
            
ElseIf Not Intersect(Range("C:C"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    
    If Target.Value = "Grey" Then
        
        Call Mail2
             
    End If
        
End If
        
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: `Target.Parent` could be simplified to `Me` too.

Comment: Works great. Instant help. Thanks alot!